# HiveQL / SQL - How to split a column to different columns based on a delimiter character

Tags: sql, hive

I have a column called "category_tree", it contains different product levels. The maximum level is 4.  For example:

```
Makeup > Lips > Lip Stain > Others
```

I want to split this value to 4 columns with name of level1, level2, level3 and level4, and the character ">" will be the separator.

```
Level1: Makeup
Level2: Lips
Level3: Lip Stain
Level4: Others
```

If the column value has only three or LESS levels, I want the 4th level / or 3th/2nd level to be Null.

```
Makeup > Eyes > Eyebrows

Level1: Makeup
Level2: Eyes
Level3: Eyebrows
Level4: (Null)
```

What might be the easiest SQL code/function to do this?  I was thinking about case function + split..

Comment: How do you identify how many records in a table belong to category, or will there be another col (let say col1) to say how many categories each col1 value has

Answer (score 0):

```
select category_tree, 
trim(split(category_tree,'>')[0]) as level1, 
trim(split(category_tree,'>')[1]) as level2,
trim(split(category_tree,'>')[2]) as level3,
trim(split(category_tree,'>')[3]) as level4
from wh_poc.xxxxxx
limit 600;
```

I tested above code and it worked~  If you have any other ideas please share. Thanks.